# New compile errors on iOS 7.1 SDK targeting iOS 7.0 deployment target

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7.1, xcode5.1

Just updated my local SDK to iOS 7.1 and Xcode to 5.1. All is fine but when I tried to compile a perfectly fine 7.0 codebase targeting the Simulator it runs fine but when I tried to target a device that runs iOS 7.1 it gave a whole set of new compile errors. There's just a lot to list out here but the more prominent one is from the famous SVPRogressHUD.

Is anything changed in iOS 7.1 SDK that need treatments differently? This is so annoying for the past hour or so.

Comment: Can you post the compile errors?

Comment: Was there ever a resolution on this?